# Electrophilic aromatic substitution reaction of dihydrofuran-2,5-dione with anisole

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

[image: Reaction Scheme]

I am having trouble understanding the reaction of anisole with dihydrofuran-2,5-dione (succinic anhydride) in presence of $\ce{AlCl3}$ and acid works or how an electrophile is formed. I feel like the product should be something like $\ce{C11H12O4}$.

Comment: This looks like a [Friedel-Crafts acylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedel%E2%80%93Crafts_reaction#Friedel.E2.80.93Crafts_acylation) to me. Maybe it all becomes clear after visiting the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice! You've brought everything you need.

If you can't identify your electrophile immediately, do it the other way around: Assign function to all components. The one that is left must be your electrophile - or its precursor.

Do you remember the role of $\ce{AlCl3}$ in electrophilic aromatic substitutions? Where could it possible attack here?

---

Here is another hint: What is the trivial name for dihydrofuran-2,5-dione?